# Calling a Function from another class using Extends in PHP

Tags: php

How can I use this openConnection() function to my other class using "extends" this is what i've tried but it is not working

**DBconnection.php**

```
class DBConnection {

   private $host;
   private $username;
   private $password;
   private $dbsource;

   private $options;
   public  $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host     = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
        $this->username = $_ENV['DB_USER'];
        $this->password = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
        $this->dbsource = $_ENV['DBSOURCE'];
        $this->conn     = "";
    }

     public function openConnection(){
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->dbsource, $this->username, $this->password,$this->options);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $this->conn;
    }   
 }
```

**TestClass.php**

```
class TestClass extends DBConnection {

  public $conn;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = $this->openConnection();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working? https://3v4l.org/k3c3F <- the method is clearly called. Note that your sample is missing an opening brace for your `DBConnection` class (I'm guessing this is a bad copy-paste). You should also call the parent constructor from the inherited one (edit: see below answer by @Cid).

Comment: @Jeto parents fields aren't initialized

Comment: it says  Call to undefined method TestClassDB::openConnection()

Comment: the brackets are ok just missin it on copy-paste

Comment: See @Cid's answer for data initialization. But this should not generate that error anyway. `openConnection` is still callable, as shown in the sample link above.

Comment: Could be another Copy/Paste error, but you shown us the class `TestClass` and your error message is about `TestClassDB` class

Comment: it is already working i only miss one line   
`public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->conn = $this->openConnection();
  }`

Comment: extends  work work if you call to a function in first class to in a function in second class. well it didnt for me. But got a very easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initializing properties in the parent class constructor, then you have to call `parent::__construct()` :

```
<?php
class foo
{
    private $message;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->message = "Hello World";
    }

    public function Bla()
    {
        echo $this->message . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class bar extends foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->Bla();
    }
}

$obj = new bar();
```

This outputs

> Hello World

Answer (score 0):

İf your both classes in seperate files extends wont work (it didnt for me).
I was needed to not change my own connection : https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql into a class

Here is your first class

```
class DBConnection {

    /** @var DBConnection */
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }    
    function runQuery($sql, $params) {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here your second class in another file

```
require_once "../db.php";
require "DBConnection.php";

    class TestClass {

        /** @var DBConnection */
        private $DBConnection;

        public function __construct($DBConnection) {
            $this->DBConnection = $DBConnection;
        }

        function getMemberByUsername($username) {
            $sql = "Select * from users where username = ?";
            //Here I call a function in first class
            $result = $this->DBConnection->runQuery($sql, array($username));
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

And here is the usaqe :

```
$DBConnection = new DBConnection($pdo);
$auth = new TestClass($DBConnection);
$auth->getMemberByUsername($username);
```

Special thanks to [Your Common Sence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)  AND @droopsnoot from sitepoint https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-call-a-function-from-class-one-into-a-function-in-class-two/346114/10 for showing the way.